# Bathroom lights occassionally flicker but stop when bidet fan runs

Tags: led, fans, bulb

In my bathroom the LED bulbs in the two lamps flicker occassionally, not always, maybe 40% of the time. When they do flicker, the flickering will stop and the bulbs glow steadily when the bidet fan is turned on. The flickering resumes when the fan is turned off. What would cause this and how is it repaired?

Comment: A) Have you searched this site for "flicker LED" and tried all the things listed in those questions? B) Do you have a dimmer switch or a regular toggle switch?

Comment: replace the bulbs. seriously.

Comment: Searched for flicker but found nothing exactly like my issue. The light switch is a toggle. The bulbs are new. I have to tell you I have not seen the issue in the last couple of weeks. I think there might be a combination of devices on the circuit which when they're simultaneously on this occurs.

Answer (score 1):

An electrical engineer may be able to explain it better than me.  The fan when running cancels the "pulse" of the AC power to the bulbs making it more level or constant. That is why the bulbs don't flicker with the fan on.
Why do they flicker at all?
Perhaps a non compatible dimmer.
Incorrect bulbs used in a fixture.
Low quality bulbs.
Fixture not grounded properly.
Incorrect wiring.
More info about the type of lighting in the bath would be helpful.

Comment: AC should have a pulse, it's a sine waveform. If that wave were level or constant, it wouldn't be AC. Please take another crack at this answer to better explain what you mean.

Comment: @dandavis, if you know more, you explain it better.

Comment: @RMDman, I think what you're saying is that the fan draws more amps (which it does) and that may be affecting the circuit. But why would the affect be an improvement (i.e., stopping the flicker)? Anyhow, as I said in a previous comment, the problem seems to have gone away. I haven't seen it in the last couple of weeks. I believe there's a particular combination of turned-on devices on the circuit that may be the cause. Thanks for all your comments!

Comment: @Phil,  My info came from a friend that is a lighting engineer for a rock band.  In his arsenal he keeps a box-fan.  I presumed for cooling, but he told me in some venues the new LED lights would flicker and if he added the fan to the circuit it canceled the problem.  He isn't an electrical engineer, so he didn't know exactly why, but was told it had to do with "evening out the pulse".  He also said, "I don't care why, it just makes my job easier."